Construct a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which has exactly three limit points, at $- \infty, 0,$ and $+ \infty$
Definition. Let us say that a sequence $(a_n)_{n=M}^{\infty}$ of real numbers has $+\infty$ as a limit point iff it has no finite upper bound, and that it has $-\infty$ as a limit point iff it has no finite lower bound.
Exercise. Using the above definition, construct a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which has exactly three limit points, at $- \infty, 0,$ and $+ \infty$.
The above exercise comes from Analysis I, 3rd edition, Terence Tao. I have presented my solution below.
For Part I below, I construct the sequence and try to rigorously show that it has the said limit points (I really only show that $+\infty$ and $0$ are limit points. To show $-\infty$ would follow a similar proof for $+\infty$). For this part, I am hoping someone can make sure my proofs are valid.
For Part II below, I tried to show that $- \infty, 0,$ and $+ \infty$ are the only limit points. Here I had trouble. Could someone let me know if there's any way I can show this based on my constructed sequence and based on my attempt? Any hints?

Part I
Let $D_1 = \{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, \ldots\}$ and let $D_2 = \{3, 6, 9, 12, \ldots\}$. Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by
$$
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
n(-1)^n & \ \text{if} \ \ n \in D_1 \\ \tag{1}
0 & \ \text{if} \ \ n \in D_2
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, the sequence is
$$
-1 ,2, 0, 4, -5, 0 ,-7,8 ,0, \ldots
$$
I'm going to show $+ \infty$ is a limit point by showing the sequence has no finite upper bound.
Suppose, for sake of contradiction, the sequence has a finite upper bound $M \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a_n \leq M$ for all $n \geq 1$. There's a result which states that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $M \leq N$. For this $N$, there must exist an even $N' \in D_1$ such that $N < N'$, implying $M \leq N < N'$. Observe that, since $N'$ is even,
$$
N' = N'(-1)^{N'} = a_{N'}
$$
where the second equality follows from $(1)$. Since $M \leq N < N' = a_{N'}$, we have that $M < a_{N'}$. But this contradicts that $a_n \leq M$ for all $n \geq 1$. Thus, we must have that the sequence has no finite upper bound. By the definition above, $+ \infty$ is a limit point of the sequence. By an analogous argument, $- \infty$ is also a limit point of the sequence.
Now I show that $0$ is a limit point of the sequence. We have to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and every $N \geq 1$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that $|n(-1)^n - 0| = |n(-1)^n| \leq \varepsilon$.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $N \geq 1$. Choose an $n \in D_2$ such that $n \geq N$. By $(1)$, this choice of $n$ implies $|n(-1)^n| = |0| = 0 \leq \varepsilon$. Thus, $0$ is a limit point of the sequence too.
Part II
Now I try to show $- \infty, 0,$ and $+ \infty$ are the only limit points of the sequence. Suppose, for sake of contradiction, $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point where $c \neq 0$. This implies that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and every $N \geq 1$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that, by $(1)$, either
$$
|n(-1)^n - c| \leq \varepsilon, \ \ \text{if}  \ n \in D_1 \tag{2}
$$
or
$$
|0 - c| \leq \varepsilon, \ \ \text{if}  \ n \in D_2 \tag{3}
$$
If it's case $(3)$, then it implies that $c=0$. But this contradicts that $c \neq 0$.
Now consider case $(2)$. It implies that $c - \varepsilon \leq n(-1)^n \leq c + \varepsilon$. To show a contradiction, I tried to show there exists an $N \geq 1$ such that $|n(-1)^n - c| > \varepsilon$ for every $n \geq N$. I was successful in showing this only for even $n \in D_1$, so that does not work.
And now I am stuck.

How about the sequence formed from the pattern $0,n,-n$?

@copper.hat That sequence works. Are you saying I'd have an easier time showing what I wanted to show?

For the sequence $~-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -3, 0, 3, \cdots~$ there isn't really anything that needs to be shown.  $~-\infty, 0, +\infty~$ are the respective limits of the subsequences $~-1, -2, -3, \cdots, ~$ and $~0,0,0,\cdots,~$ and $~1,2,3,\cdots.$  A value is a limit point of a sequence if and only if it is the limit of a subsequence.

@user2661923 at this point in the text, we did not cover subsequences.

Put \begin{equation}
a_n =
\begin{cases}
k & if \quad  = 3k, \
0 & if \quad n = 3k-1, \
-k & if \quad n = 3k-2.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We get $a_1, a_2, \ldots = -1,0,1,-2,0,2,-3,0,3...$ as in
user2661923 's comment.

The sequence that you have chosen will work, but in these exercises it is important to be precise with the line of reasoning. It is clear from the choice of sequence (and what you have said in part I) that the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has subsequences $(a_{3n})_{n=1}^\infty, (a_{6n+2})_{n=1}^\infty, (a_{6n+1})_{n=1}^\infty$ with limit points $0$, $\infty$, and $-\infty$ respectively. Therefore, $(a_n)$ has limit points $0$, $\infty$, and $-\infty$.
$$ $$
Now we show these are the only limit points. Thus, assume there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $n$ such that $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$. Your argument is no longer solid on the next step. Suppose $c$ is not an integer. Let $m$ be the closest integer to $c$, and let $\epsilon = |m - c|$. By assumption there exists an $n$ such that $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$, but since $m$ is the closest integer to $c$, $\epsilon = |m-c| \leq |a_n - c| < \epsilon$, a contradiction. Thus, $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, and assume $c \neq 0$. Now take $\epsilon = .5$. Since each non-zero integer appears in $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ at most once, let $m$ be the index where $a_m = c$ or $m = 1$ if $c$ never appears. Then letting $N = m+1$, for every $n \geq N$, $|a_n - a_m| \geq 1 > \epsilon$, a contradiction. Thus, either $c = \infty, -\infty$, or $c = 0$.

Thank you for your answer. I have a couple of questions for you.  (1) Your definition of limit point uses $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$ rather than $|a_n - c| \leq \epsilon$. Using the latter, then $\epsilon = |m-c| \leq |a_n - c| \leq \epsilon$ would not lead to a contradiction since $\epsilon \leq \epsilon$ is true. I'm assuming there's an easy fix though, right?

(2) I see how taking $\epsilon = .5$ to show $|a_n - a_m| \geq 1 > \epsilon$ leads to a contradiction. But I thought we would have to show $|a_n - c| > \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

For your first question, there must be some $n$ such that $|a_n-c| \leq \epsilon /2$. For the second, try revisiting the definitions.

Oh, you're right. The negation of "for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that $|a_n - c| \leq \epsilon$" is "there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ and an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - c| > \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$".
